# uploading docx in php works half the time

Tags: php, uploading

I'm making a simple document management system. It is implemented on two different servers. One has a weird bug and the other doesn't. 
While uploading a file (same file in all cases mentioned below)

On the buggy server:

```
print_r($sUploadFile);
die();
```

yields:

```
Array ( [name] => Human Resources.docx [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )
```

which isn't too useful. I cant figure out why error is set. On the not buggy server it yields:

Array ( [name] => Human Resources.docx [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document [tmp_name] => /tmp/phploctg0 [error] => 0 [size] => 2211177 )

In both cases sUploadFile comes from an html form and in both cases I'm grabbing a working docx file from my desktop.

Any ideas why the file array works on one server and not the other? Ideally this solution should be platform indepent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific [file upload error code](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) means that the file is larger than the server's `upload_max_filesize` limit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uploading files of different sizes to the "buggy" server? There's a maximum file size you can upload to PHP, modifiable via php.ini. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php